# SQL what is faster left 2 or convert(varchar(2),'Chgffgjjx')

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

If I want to return the first two characters of a string which is the best / fastest method?

Also if I have a date and want to group by day I will use `convert(varchar(10),getdate())` 
as our db format is in yyyy/MM/dd, which would give '2010/02/10' if I wanted to group by month I would use `varchar(7)` instead to give '2010/02'

Is there a faster way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference in performance between these two.  However - and this is not entirely clear from your question - if you are putting this into a `WHERE` condition as opposed to the column output of your query, both are very, very bad.

String functions such as `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING` and `CONVERT` (when used for casting) are non-sargable, which means that an ordinarily efficient index seek will be turned into an expensive full index scan.  If you want to query on the first two characters of a field, you should write the query as such:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ...
FROM Table
WHERE StringCol LIKE 'AB%'
```

Again, this only applies for filters; if the `LEFT`/`SUBSTRING` is in the column output (i.e. `SELECT LEFT(Col1, 2)`) then you need not worry about the performance.

Comment: Why would `LEFT` not be SARGable?

Answer (score 1):

The results for the Compute Scalar portion of the query are identical for using `LEFT(t.col, 2)` and `CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), t.col)`:

```
Estimated CPU Cost:       0.0283193
Estimated I/O Cost:       0
Estimated Number of Rows: 283193
Estimated Operator Cost:  0.028 (0%)
```

SQL Server 2005

My assumption is that `LEFT` is a synonym for CAST/CONVERT...

Comment: +1 for getting detailed information from the execution plan - far more precise than timed queries.

Answer (score 1):

1) If I want to return the first two characters of a string which is the best / fastest method?

LEFT('YourString', 2) is IMHO the more natural, more readable in terms of shouting and screaming it's intention. I really don't think this will be a cause of poor performance - much more likely to hit poor performance from a poorly constructed query, missing indexes etc. I'd just stick with what feels natural, and simplest.

2) Also if I have a date and want to group by day I will use convert(varchar(10),getdate()) as our db format is in yyyy/MM/dd, which would give '2010/02/10' if I wanted to group by month I would use varchar(7) instead to give '2010/02'

When converting dates, I'd always specify the last parameter of CONVERT which is the style.
e.g.

```
-- 112 = ISO format. This would give yyyyMM
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Note this is a good example of what I said above re: other areas more likely to perform worse. If you apply the CONVERT to a column in a query's WHERE clause, it prevents the index on that column being used. So instead, I'd change the query to have a date range specified with the start date = the start of the month and the end date = the 1st day of the next month:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable
WHERE DateField >= @StartOfMonth AND DateField < @FirstDayOfNextMonth
```

This would use an index on DateField giving better performance than a CONVERT approach

Answer (score 1):

As for your 2nd question: Don't use this CONVERT() method if you're operating on a larger table. A more effective method would to use something like

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, < your datetime column >), 0)
```

to group by day and likewise

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, < your datetime column >), 0)
```

to group by month.

Answer (score 0):

A1. `LEFT` of course, how could you do less work than use a function that explicitly does only that?

A2. Don't store `DATE`s as varchars, store them as dates and index them, this makes ordering lightening fast, and you can use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(SQL.80).aspx) to get at certain components of the date.

Comment: It doesn't look he is storing dates as `varchar` - the syntax above indicates a conversion *to* `varchar`, with the source being a date.

Comment: Well then just use the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(SQL.80).aspx) function, dates are formatted there is no reason to serialize them to a random format, just to extract them with a stupid rudimentary method.

Answer (score -1):

test it out:

```
DECLARE @x int
       ,@RunDate datetime
       ,@y  char(2)
       ,@z int
       ,@total int
       ,@tries int

SELECT @z=1,@total=0,@tries=20

WHILE @z<=@tries
BEGIN
    SELECT @RunDate=GETDATE(),@x=1,@z=@z+1
    WHILE @x<500000
    BEGIN
       SET @x=@x+1
       SELECT @x=@x+1,@y=LEFT('Chgffgjjx',2)
    END
    PRINT RIGHT(' '+CONVERT(varchar(2),@z-1),2)+' - LEFT() Took: '+CONVERT(varchar(20),datediff(ms,@RunDate,GETDATE()))+' milliseconds'
    SET @total=@total+CONVERT(varchar(20),datediff(ms,@RunDate,GETDATE()))
END
PRINT 'LEFT() average: '+CONVERT(varchar(20),@total/(1.0+@tries))
SELECT @z=1,@total=0,@tries=20
WHILE @z<=@tries
BEGIN

    SELECT @RunDate=GETDATE(),@x=1,@z=@z+1
    WHILE @x<500000
    BEGIN
       SET @x=@x+1
       SELECT @x=@x+1,@y=CONVERT(varchar(2),'Chgffgjjx')
    END
    PRINT RIGHT(' '+CONVERT(varchar(2),@z-1),2)+' - CONVERT() Took: '+CONVERT(varchar(20),datediff(ms,@RunDate,GETDATE()))+' milliseconds'
    SET @total=@total+CONVERT(varchar(20),datediff(ms,@RunDate,GETDATE()))
END
PRINT 'CONVERT() average: '+CONVERT(varchar(20),@total/(1.0+@tries))
```

OUTPUT:

```
 1 - LEFT() Took: 563 milliseconds
 2 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
 3 - LEFT() Took: 406 milliseconds
 4 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
 5 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
 6 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
 7 - LEFT() Took: 393 milliseconds
 8 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
 9 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
10 - LEFT() Took: 486 milliseconds
11 - LEFT() Took: 686 milliseconds
12 - LEFT() Took: 453 milliseconds
13 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
14 - LEFT() Took: 406 milliseconds
15 - LEFT() Took: 403 milliseconds
16 - LEFT() Took: 410 milliseconds
17 - LEFT() Took: 560 milliseconds
18 - LEFT() Took: 546 milliseconds
19 - LEFT() Took: 593 milliseconds
20 - LEFT() Took: 390 milliseconds
LEFT() average: 429.7619047619047
 1 - CONVERT() Took: 440 milliseconds
 2 - CONVERT() Took: 513 milliseconds
 3 - CONVERT() Took: 393 milliseconds
 4 - CONVERT() Took: 453 milliseconds
 5 - CONVERT() Took: 390 milliseconds
 6 - CONVERT() Took: 406 milliseconds
 7 - CONVERT() Took: 420 milliseconds
 8 - CONVERT() Took: 406 milliseconds
 9 - CONVERT() Took: 390 milliseconds
10 - CONVERT() Took: 390 milliseconds
11 - CONVERT() Took: 406 milliseconds
12 - CONVERT() Took: 390 milliseconds
13 - CONVERT() Took: 626 milliseconds
14 - CONVERT() Took: 593 milliseconds
15 - CONVERT() Took: 423 milliseconds
16 - CONVERT() Took: 406 milliseconds
17 - CONVERT() Took: 450 milliseconds
18 - CONVERT() Took: 486 milliseconds
19 - CONVERT() Took: 406 milliseconds
20 - CONVERT() Took: 390 milliseconds
CONVERT() average: 417.9523809523809
```

they seem very close to me